# regex to get the number from the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a id like stringNumber variable like the one as follows : example12
I need some javascript regex to extract 12 from the string."example" will be constant for all id and just the number will be different.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This regular expression matches numbers at the end of the string.

```
var matches = str.match(/\d+$/);
```

It will return an `Array` with its `0`th element the match, if successful. Otherwise, it will return `null`.

Before accessing the `0` member, ensure the match was made.

```
if (matches) {
    number = matches[0];
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayt9S/).

If you must have it as a `Number`, you can use a function to convert it, such as `parseInt()`.

```
number = parseInt(number, 10);
```

Comment: Tip: It is more efficient to use `[0-9]` than it is to use `\d` . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738

Comment: @Marathon55 Very well might be the case, but I'd still use `\d` myself (unless it became a performance bottleneck)

Answer (score 15):

RegEx:

```
var str = "example12";
parseInt(str.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);
```

String manipulation:

```
var str = "example12",
    prefix = "example";
parseInt(str.substring(prefix.length), 10);
```