# Angular: Split json data on each row

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a json array which looks like this:

```
data: Array(8)
0: (3) ["test1", "4.96", "150"]
1: (3) ["test2", "156.16666666666666", "150"]
2: (3) ["test3", "279.3695652173913", "92"]
3: (3) ["test4", "1718", "16"]
4: (3) ["test5", "2.375", "16"]
5: (3) ["test6", "2230.6875", "16"]
6: (3) ["test7", "23.75", "32"]
```

I have a method to split the array:

```
data.forEach(test => {
    result.run.data.push([
        Number(test[0].split('test')[1]),
        Number(test[1])
    ]);

    result.count.data.push([
        Number(test[0].split('test')[1]),
        Number(test[2])
    ]);
});
```

As you can see, i split the array at "test". My problem is, the test-string could be different. I want the same mapping to be done when the json looks slightly different although has the same structure.

For example the json array looks like this:

```
 data: Array(8)
0: (3) ["asdf1", "4.96", "150"]
1: (3) ["fasd2", "156.16666666666666", "150"]
2: (3) ["qwer3", "279.3695652173913", "92"]
3: (3) ["llll4", "1718", "16"]
4: (3) ["rwwe5", "2.375", "16"]
5: (3) ["ttgd6", "2230.6875", "16"]
6: (3) ["34227", "23.75", "32"]
```

I would like it to split the same way as i do the first array.

How can i change my method to split the array at the start of each row instead of a string?

Comment: you can define the variable(lets say prefix) in environment.json file and use the value of prefix to split the array as your doing currently.

Comment: I couldn't understand the code. Can you be more clear with the output of the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function for the same and pass key as param something like

```
spiltData(data,splitKey){
data.forEach(test => {
    result.run.data.push([
        Number(test[0].split(splitKey)[1]),
        Number(test[1])
    ]);

    result.count.data.push([
        Number(test[0].split(splitKey)[1]),
        Number(test[2])
    ]);
});
}
```

then use like

```
 this.spiltData(data,'test')
 this.spiltData(data,'asdf')
```

I am not sure about `result.count` & `result.run` here but you can pass them as param as well

**Update**

if key can be any dynamic string and not known to you and there will be only one number in string then you can use [regex to get the number from the end of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340180/regex-to-get-the-number-from-the-end-of-a-string) show your code should look like

```
spiltData(data){
    data.forEach(test => {
        var matches=test[0].match(/\d+$/);
        result.run.data.push([
            Number( matches ? matches[0] : 0),
            Number(test[1])
        ]);

        result.count.data.push([
            Number(matches ? matches[0] : 0),
            Number(test[2])
        ]);
    });
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to do this standarized? my problem is that the values like "asdf" and "test" always change. I can't change the params each time

Comment: i edited my example to resemble what i'm meaning, check the second array

Answer (score 2):

Instead of split You could consider using regex to extract a number from string

```
console.log(/\d+/.exec('test1')) --> ["1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `Number(test[0].split('test')[1])`

with

`Number(test[0].split('').filter(x => !isNaN(parseInt(x, 10))))`

Try like this:

```
this.data.forEach(test => {
  this.result.run.data.push([
    Number(test[0].split('').filter(x => !isNaN(parseInt(x, 10)))),
    Number(test[1])
  ]);

  ...
});
```

**See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyzhby?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forEach(test => {
    result.run.data.push([
        Number(/(\d+)$/.exec(test[0])[1]),
        Number(test[1])
    ]);

    result.count.data.push([
        Number(/(\d+)$/.exec(test[0])[1]),
        Number(test[2])
    ]);
});
```

Comment: with this I get core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null